Layer count mismatch while loading svae deocder part in an Autoencoder model for image
I develop a simple autoencoder model for image.
Once trained, I saved encoder and decoder part in h5 file.
Model training code :
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, Dropout, LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import numpy as np
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint,EarlyStopping,ReduceLROnPlateau
import os
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Define input sequence7# Define input shape
input_shape = (256, 256, 1)

# Encoder
inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='swish', padding='same')(inputs)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='swish', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='swish', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

encoded = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='swish', padding='same')(x)

# Decoder
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='swish', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)

x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='swish', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)

x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='swish', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)

decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)



autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoded, name='autoencoder')
autoencoder.summary()

data = "data"

def train_test_split(dir_path, split_th):
    imgs = os.listdir(dir_path)
    imgs.sort()
    len_img = len(imgs)

    len_train = int(len_img*split_th)

    train, test = [], []

    for i in range(len_train):
        train.append(os.path.join(dir_path, imgs[i]))
    for i in range(len_train, len_img):
        test.append(os.path.join(dir_path, imgs[i]))
    return train, test

def preprocess_data(data):
    tmp_x = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        image = Image.open(data[i])
        image = asarray(image).astype('float32')
        image = image/255
        tmp_x.append(image)

    return tmp_x

train, test = train_test_split(data, 0.8)
x_train = preprocess_data(train)
x_test = preprocess_data(test)

# Normalize data
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 256, 256, 1))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 256, 256, 1))

x_train.shape

# Define input shape
input_shape = x_train.shape[1:]

# Train autoencoder

earlystopper = EarlyStopping(patience=10, verbose=1)

reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2,patience=2, min_lr=0.000001, verbose=1, cooldown=1)

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adamax', loss='mse')
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('/kaggle/working/autoencoder_weights.keras', monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
history = autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=10,
                batch_size=16,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test, x_test),
                callbacks=[checkpoint, reduce_lr, earlystopper])

encoder = Model(inputs, encoded)
tmp = encoder.predict(x_test)

tmp.shape

encoder.save("final_encoder_model.h5")

decoder = Model(encoded, decoded)

decoder.save("final_decoder_model1.h5")

tmp2 = decoder.predict(tmp)

tmp.shape

encoder.summary()

decoded.summary()



code to load model :
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

decoder = load_model("final_decoder_model1.h5")

When I am loading encoder model it is loading correct but for decoder model, I am getting this error :
ValueError: Layer count mismatch when loading weights from file. Model expected 4 layers, found 8 saved layers.
Sample data : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o6cinLfqPzCmGZaNxHt9tK9OFpjXwDux/view?usp=sharing
I tried to load the model in pycharm. It is ok if it works at kaggle notebook, jupyter, colab or any other editor.
